# Method overriding using java generics?

Tags: java, generics

While running this code i am getting an error on the lines which i have commented. so please help me to resolve this problem that how we can overload the functions using java generics.

```
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String... args) 
{
    Main.<Integer>print();
    Main.<Short>print();//   error
    Main.<Byte>print();// error
    Main.<Void>print();//error
}

public static <T extends Integer> int print() 
{
    System.out.println("here - Integer");
    return 0;
}
public static <T extends Short> short print()  //error
{
    System.out.println("here - Short");
    return 0;
}
public static <T extends Byte> byte print() //error
{
    System.out.println("here - Byte");
    return 0;
}
public static <T extends Void> void print() //error
{
    System.out.println("here - Void");
}
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile ?

Comment: and this is not method overriding.

Comment: This is method **overloading**, yes

Comment: This is not supposed to work, due to type erasure of generics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html, because the method signatures at run time would be the same.

Comment: That code can't compile. You may not have two methods that have the same name & parameters in a class.

Comment: no it doesn't compile

Answer (score 4):

These methods are not really generic despite having a generic type parameter. Also their signature is the same, java cannot diferentiate functions based on return values.

what you might want to have is a

```
public static <T> void print(T t) {
             System.out.println(t.getClass());
}
```

that's the closest to what you're trying to achieve as far as i understood it.

Also please take a look at oracle's [generics documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to understand generics

Answer (score 1):

Java compile is not able to determine which method to call. Because return type is not enough for compile to decide whom to call.
Overload function with parameter type.

Check following code:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        Main.print();
        Main.print(1);//   int
        short s = 5;
        Main.print(s);// error
        byte b = 57;
        Main.print(b);//error
    }

    public static int print(int x) 
    {
        System.out.println("here - Integer :" + x);
        return 0;
    }
    public static short print(short y) 
    {
        System.out.println("here - Short :" + y);
        return 0;
    }
    public static byte print(byte b)
    {
        System.out.println("here - Byte :" + b);
        return 0;
    }
    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.println("here - Void");
    }
}
```

output :

```
here - Void
here - Integer :1
here - Short :5
here - Byte :57
```

mark it up^ if it helps you...

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not need generics at all. Derived from your example code you should refactor it this way:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    printInteger();
    printShort();
    printByte();
    print();
}

public static int printInteger() {
    System.out.println("here - Integer");
    return 0;
}

public static short printShort() {
    System.out.println("here - Short");
    return 0;
}

public static byte printByte() {
    System.out.println("here - Byte");
    return 0;
}

public static void print() {
    System.out.println("here - Void");
}
```

But why do you return `0` all the times? If you want to print a value passed into the print method do it this way instead:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int i = 42;
    short s = 42;
    byte b = 42;
    print(i);
    print(s);
    print(b);
    print();
}

public static void print(int value) {
    System.out.println("here - Integer: " + value);
}

public static void print(short value) {
    System.out.println("here - Short: " + value);
}

public static void print(byte value) {
    System.out.println("here - Byte: " + value);
}

public static void print() {
    System.out.println("here - Void");
}
```